# Freopen Multiple File input - C++

Tags: c++, freopen

I have tried this

```
...
for(int i=0;i<totalDoc;i++){
        freopen(name[i],"r",stdin);
        while(cin>>s!=NULL){doc[i]=doc[i]+s+" ";}
        fclose(stdin);
        ...
}
```

with `name` is a char "doc1.txt", "doc2.txt", ...

but, this code only open "doc1.txt", can somebody help me please?

Comment: Is the above crappy code even compiling ?

Comment: And you forgot to give the declarations of `name` and `doc`

Comment: And `"doc1.txt"` is *not* a `char` constant (like `'d'` is)!

Comment: my code is compiled, so that's why I know it's only open doc1.txt

Comment: hehe, thanks for the answer @BasileStarynkevitch, I'm using freopen because I used to before and its work, but, I forget I use cin today

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Are you coding in C or in C++ ? You have to choose!</sup>

You should read the documentation of [freopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/freopen.3.html) and use its result.

> ```
>    The freopen() function opens the file whose name is the string
>    pointed to by path and associates the stream pointed to by stream
>    with it.  The original stream (if it exists) is closed.
> ```

Also, you should not mix C++ I/O streams (e.g. `std::cin` and `>>`)  with C files (e.g. `stdin` and `fscanf`...).

I strongly suggest you to spend several hours reading more documentation (don't use any header, function or type without having read its documentation) and books. Your code is pityful.

So you might code in *C* :

```
for(int i=0;i<totalDoc;i++){
   FILE*inf = freopen(name[i],"r",stdin); // wrong
   if (!inf) { perror(name[i]); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

but that won't work on the second iteration (since `stdin` has been closed by the first call to `freopen`), so you really want to use `fopen`, not `freopen` and read from that `inf` file. Don't forget to `fclose` it at the end of your `for` loop body.

BTW, if you code in C++ (and you have to choose between C and C++, they are different languages) you would simply use an [std::ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/), perhaps like

```
for(int i=0;i<totalDoc;i++){
   std::ifstream ins(name[i]);
   while (ins.good()) {
     std::string s;
     ins >> s;
     doc[i] += s + " ";
   };
}
```

At last, choose which language and which standard you code in ([C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) is different of [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)) and read more documentation. Also, compile with all warnings and debug info enabled (e.g. `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g` for C++11 code or `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -g` for C99 code, if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) and **use the debugger**.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous solution mentioned freopen can only be used for one file at a time. Thus to get around this for File IO in C++ I'd look at this source and use fstreams: https://www.bgsu.edu/arts-and-sciences/computer-science/cs-documentation/reading-data-from-files-using-c-plus-plus.html

An example way to open multiple files is

```
int a, b;
in.open("file1"); 
in >> a;
in.close();

in.open("file2");
in >> b;
in.close();
```